# Sending text with new lines over network

Tags: java, networking, client-server

I am trying to send text with new lines over a network in Java. For example:

> "hello \n this is a new line"

Here is my code I am using for the client:

```
Socket kkSocket = null;
PrintWriter out = null;
BufferedReader in = null;

/*connect to server here*/

BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String fromServer;
String fromUser;

while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.print("Server: " + fromServer);
    if (fromServer.equals("Bye.")) {
        break;
    }

    fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
    if (fromUser != null) {
        System.out.print("Client: " + fromUser);
        out.println(fromUser);
    }
}

out.close();
in.close();
stdIn.close();
kkSocket.close();
```

And here is the code I am using for the server:

```
/*Connect to server here*/
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
String inputLine, outputLine;
Protocol kkp = new Protocol();

outputLine = kkp.processInput(null);
out.println(outputLine);

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    outputLine = kkp.processInput(inputLine);
    out.println(outputLine);
    if (outputLine.equals("Bye.")) break;
}
```

But it only returns the first line.

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction so I can use new lines?

Comment: `while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null)` : your client seems to be expecting something from the server to continue. Is your server sending anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to note is that `readLine()` method uses line terminators `\n` being one of them, that the reason the remaining text is not included, inorder for that to happen you have to call the `readLine()` method again. In your case i would have used the `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` method that reads `char[]` as follows :

Instead of using `readLine()` use `read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)` to read as follows

```
char[] cbuf = new char[1024];
while (in.read(cbuf, 0, cbuf.length) != null) {
    fromServer =  new String(cbuf);
    System.out.print("Server: " + fromServer);
    if (fromServer.equals("Bye.")) {
        break;
    }

    fromUser = stdIn.readLine();
    if (fromUser != null) {
        System.out.print("Client: " + fromUser);
        out.println(fromUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: `readLine()` does not 'ignore' anything. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP I'm getting an error with the while statement: "incomparable type: int and nulltype" any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to check if an `int` is `null`?

Comment: @tmwanik I don't know who you are. But if I ever meet you in real life I'm buying you a beer. Null just needed to be changed to 0.

thank you so much. Been pulling my hair out over this.

Comment: @tmwanik actually, i've bumped into a problem. When the the above is completed, the java console scrolls to the far right. Any ideas?